# TCP sampler request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a java program that acts as s TCP server and I need to test its performance.
Written a tcp sampler jmeter request and I am able to get response data correctly but the response code is 500 and there are errors thrown in logs

```
TCPClientClassName : TCPClientImpl
Response : 500
Checked "Reuse Connection", "Set No Delay" options

Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2014-10-15 17:33:51 IST
Load time: 514
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 14
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 14
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException:
```

Exception in logs

```
2014/10/15 17:35:14 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2014/10/15 17:35:14 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2014/10/15 17:35:14 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2014/10/15 17:35:14 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2014/10/15 17:35:14 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 
2014/10/15 17:35:14 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2014/10/15 17:35:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1      perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2014/10/15 17:35:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2014/10/15 17:35:14 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2014/10/15 17:35:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2014/10/15 17:35:14 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPClientImpl: Using platform default charset:windows- 1252 
2014/10/15 17:35:14 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler: Using eolByte=10 
2014/10/15 17:35:15 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler:    org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: 
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPClientImpl.read(TCPClientImpl.java:117)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler.sample(TCPSampler.java:414)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPClientImpl.read(TCPClientImpl.java:104)
... 4 more

2014/10/15 17:35:15 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2014/10/15 17:35:15 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2014/10/15 17:35:15 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

Comment: "at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)", share your test script

there is something wrong you are in your test script

Comment: @JmeterPerfTest Here is the jmx file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4H-LR3qX_fRQkw4ZFBuX0hZQW8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

First, To check that your TCP server is really running, run :

> telnet host:port

If it still fails, it might be because Firewall is not open between JMeter and target server hosting your TCP server